# Is the following limit correct? $[\lim_{n\to\infty}\binom{n}{50}(\frac2n)^{50}(1-\frac2n)^{n-50}]$

Tags: limits, binomial-coefficients, poisson-distribution

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\binom{n}{50}\left(\frac2n\right)^{50}\left(1-\frac2n\right)^{n-50}$$

---

Taking $nh=1$ and $K=\binom{n}{50}\left(\frac2n\right)^{50}\left(1-\frac2n\right)^{n-50}$, we have:
$$\ln K =\ln\left[\binom{n}{50}(2h)^{50}\right]+(1-50h)\frac{\ln(1-2h)}h
\\=\ln\left[\frac{2^{50}}{50!}\prod_{k=1}^{49}(1-kh)\right]+(1-50h)\frac{\ln(1-2h)}h$$
Now I think $$\lim_{n\to\infty}K=\frac{2^{50}}{50!}\frac1{e^2}$$
Is this correct way to solve this? Is my answer correct?

**Edit:** I noted that: $$\left(\frac2n+1-\frac2n\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\underbrace{\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac2n\right)^{k}\left(1-\frac2n\right)^{n-k}}_{t_k}$$
As $n\to\infty$, LHS is exactly 1 and we need to find the minute contribution of $t_{50}$.

Comment: Well done. You have obtained the Poisson as a limiting case of the binomial. The calculation can also be done without logarithms.

Comment: Poisson=? some context?

Comment: A random variable $X$ has Poisson distribution parameter $\lambda$ if $\Pr(X=k)=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$ (for integer values of $k\ge 0$). The Poisson distribution is the limiting case of the binomial, where the number $n$ of trials is large, and the probability of success on any trial is $\frac{\lambda}{n}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas thnx for teaching the unknown! thumbs up $\uparrow$

Comment: Doing almost the same as you did, I generalized to $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\binom{n}{m}\left(\frac kn\right)^{m}\left(1-\frac kn\right)^{n-m}=\frac{e^{-k} k^m}{m!}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would approach this using the two following hints.

**Hint 1**:
$$
\binom{n}{50}\left(\frac2n\right)^{50}
=\frac{n}{n}\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{n-2}{n}\cdots\frac{n-49}{n}\frac{2^{50}}{50!}\\
$$
**Hint 2**:
$$
\left(1-\frac2n\right)^{n-50}
=\left(1-\frac2n\right)^n\left(1-\frac2n\right)^{-50}\\
$$

Comment: sorry I don't see these hints going somewhere?

Comment: Can you compute each of the following limits? $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n}\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{n-2}{n}\cdots\frac{n-49}{n}$$ $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac2n\right)^n$$ $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac2n\right)^{-50}$$

Comment: oh yes! got it!